# javaScript local script can't find function in src script

Tags: javascript

I have a javaScript source file, named LIMDU.js, that contains a var and a function, like this --

```
var SessionTimeOutID;

function KeepSessionAlive() {
var sessionTimeoutWarning = @Session.Timeout;
var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000;

clearTimeout(SessionTimeOutID);
SessionTimeOutID = setTimeout('SessionEnd()', sTimeout);

function SessionEnd() {
    window.location = "/Account/LogOff";
}
 }
```

and in the cshtml file, I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/LIMDU.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
       KeepSessionAlive();
    });
</script>
```

but when I try to execute the code, I get the error "KeepSessionAlive" not found.

I thought that the src code would be loaded before the local script code was executed; if that's not the case, how do I refer to a function in my local script block that's defined in a src'd file?

Comment: Unless you have something pre-processing it before it gets to your browser, your `LINDU.js` contains a syntax error: `var sessionTimeoutWarning = @Session.Timeout;` The error is as of the `@`. Normally, `.js` files aren't pre-processed (as `.cshtml` files are) by the server. So the first thing to do is use your browser tools to look for errors in the console, and to inspect the actual content sent to the browser by your server. If it has that syntax error in it, that's the problem.

Comment: Is that is all that is in that script file? Does `@Session.Timeout` actually get replaced? I am guessing no

Comment: Check your console. Your LIMDU.js file is not compiling (probably undefined @Session ?)

Comment: I think the misunderstanding is that you're trying to use Razor/`.cshtml` syntax in your JavaScript file - this isn't correct. You might be able to make `KeepSessionAlive` take the timeout as a parameter, and then pass `@Session.Timeout` in your .cshtml file, but I'm not an ASP guy, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your console. Your LIMDU.js file is not compiling (probably undefined @Session ?)

Comment: yes, it was that simple; the first versions had the @var in the local code, so moving that back to the cshtml fixed the main issue. Thanks for the help!